# Joining Tables with two tasks list and user list

Tags: sql, t-sql, left-join, inner-join

I have a question on joining user table in this query I built for our business. It's a small productivity report based on 7 different tasks that were completed by the user.

there are two tasks tables:
1) Checklist Task
2) Requested Task

Requested tasks are an extension of Checklist Task. 
Requested tasks have REQUESTED DATE column which is in the Requested Task Table
Requested tasks have COMPLETED DATE column which is in the Checklist Task table.

When I run the query below, obviously the SecurityIdentity Table which is only joined by the Checklist Task table by CompletedByID to display their full name.

The Task name 'Recorded Docs' which is a Requested Checklist, has Requested Date (RequestedDate from Requested Task table) and Received Date (CompletedDate from Checklist table), coming from two different tables as mentioned above.

```
SELECT o.number   AS 'OrderNo',
       s.fullname AS 'CPC Emp',
       Max(CASE
             WHEN t.description = 'Loan Package to Lender' THEN
             Dateadd(hour, -4, t.completeddate)
             ELSE NULL
           END)   AS 'Loan Pck To Lender',
       Max(CASE
             WHEN t.description = 'Recording Audit' THEN
             Dateadd(hour, -4, t.completeddate)
             ELSE NULL
           END)   AS 'Recording Audit',
       Max(CASE
             WHEN t.description = 'Recorded Docs' THEN
             Dateadd(hour, -4, rt.requesteddate)
             ELSE NULL
           END)   AS 'Recorded Docs Requested',
       Max(CASE
             WHEN t.description = 'Recorded Docs' THEN
             Dateadd(hour, -4, t.completeddate)
             ELSE NULL
           END)   AS 'Recorded Docs Received',
       Max(CASE
             WHEN t.description = 'Recorded Docs to Lender' THEN
             Dateadd(hour, -4, t.completeddate)
             ELSE NULL
           END)   AS 'Recorded Docs to Lender',
       Max(CASE
             WHEN t.description = 'Recorded Docs to Purchaser' THEN
             Dateadd(hour, -4, t.completeddate)
             ELSE NULL
           END)   AS 'Recorded Docs to Purchaser',
       Max(CASE
             WHEN t.description = 'Title Policy to Lender' THEN
             Dateadd(hour, -4, t.completeddate)
             ELSE NULL
           END)   AS 'TP to Lender',
       Max(CASE
             WHEN t.description = 'Title Policy to Purchaser' THEN
             Dateadd(hour, -4, t.completeddate)
             ELSE NULL
           END)   AS 'TP Purchaser'
FROM   pf.orderinfo oi
       INNER JOIN pfm.[order] o
               ON ( o.rootid# = oi.rootid )
       INNER JOIN core.profile op
               ON ( oi.owningprofileid = op.id )
       INNER JOIN zref.orderstatus os
               ON ( oi.orderstatus = os.id )
       INNER JOIN zref.producttype pt
               ON ( o.producttypeid = pt.id
                    AND pt.id <> '15' )
       INNER JOIN pfm.task t
               ON ( t.rootid# = oi.rootid
                    AND ( t.description IN ( 'Loan Package to Lender',
                                             'Recording Audit',
                                                 'Recorded Docs to Lender',
                                             'Recorded Docs to Purchaser',
                                             'Title Policy to Lender',
                                             'Title Policy to Purchaser'
                                             ,
                                                   'Recorded Docs' ) ) )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN pfm.requestedtask rt
                    ON ( rt.rootid# = t.rootid#
                         AND rt.id# = t.id#
                         AND rt.lastid# = t.lastid# )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN core.securityidentity s
                    ON ( s.id = t.completedbyid )
WHERE  ( op.NAME LIKE 'BH104%' -- WNCW Res Profiles Begin.
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'CL170%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'CM104%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'IN103%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'SF107%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'AW170%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'JW170%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'KH170%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'PM170%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'SC170%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'EC102%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'MT175%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'CU108%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'NF106%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'GA105%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'SL105%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'PC135%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'PE103%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'OC130%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'WF130%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'SS100%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'SO191%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'CA115%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'DO115%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'WC115%'
          OR op.NAME LIKE 'WO115%' --WNCW RES Profiles End.
             AND op.enabled = 1
             AND oi.istemplate = 0
             AND oi.number NOT LIKE '%test%'
             AND oi.number NOT LIKE 'tr%' )
       AND oi.number = 'WC115-13-0048'
       AND s.fullname IS NOT NULL
GROUP  BY s.fullname,
          o.number
ORDER  BY 2 DESC
```

When I query this sql, the result is this in red square:
[image: Result]

However, Stacey did not Request that but Kathy did. So, the result date/timestamp SHOULD be displayed as Kathy requested Recorded Docs and not Stacey.

I've tried many different ways to join the securityidentity table to correct this, but was unable to do so.. Any assistance will be greatly appreciate it!

Here are the three tables:
task
[image]

requestedtask
[image]

securityidentity

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem may be related to the ID to which you are joining in your Task table. As it is written now, it doesn't matter who requested the task, you will be showing the name of the person that completed the task because you have joined to the CompletedByID. If requesting is synonymous with assigning, then you should be joining to the AssignedToID. In any case, you need to figure out whose name you want displayed and join to the appropriate ID.

Below are some other things I noticed that could be changed/improved:

1. You're missing a closing parenthesis after *OR op.NAME LIKE 'WO115%'*. Unless you know exactly what you are trying to do, you should never allow OR and AND statements to be used in combination within the same set of parentheses.
2. You can replace all those op.Name like 'XXXX%' with one in()

Using the function below, if your Name is not indexed or you have a ton of records, you may see some significant slowing. The way you have it now is not wrong, but using the in() shown below may be easier.

```
LEFT(op.Name,4) in('XXXXX%','YYYYY%',...,'ZZZZZ%')
```

3. Finally, you have given us a ton of information here, which makes helping you easier. That said, you've given us a ton of information. From what I see, I can tell your business has something to do with mortgages or finances, which means someone might be interested in your data structure. Additionally, you've given us the table names, schema names, and the names of a handful of your employees. I'm no hacker, but I can imagine someone might find that information useful. In the future, I would consider changing up some of the business critical information or blurring more of your data in screenshots.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.